# how import data from microsoft project (2007,2010) using PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, converters, ms-project

I have been build a program using PHP. And my data resouces are from microsoft project (2007,2010) on xml format.

Anyone have experience/program converter for that ?

Thanks for a lot :)

Comment: Sorry, wrong type of question for this page. Stackoverflow is a place to ask for help on specific problems one fails to solve after own attempts. This is _not_ a general question board. Research and try yourself, if you get stuck then post what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net) useful. Although written in Java, as noted on the MPXJ home page you will be able to use a Java-PHP bridge to use its functionality from PHP.